# Rewrite a constraint on the probability distribution using the cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Consider a probability distribution $P: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow [0,1]$ and assume
$$
(\diamond) \text{ }\int_{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \text{ s.t. } x_3= x_1-x_2} dP=1
$$

Questions:

- Is there a way to rewrite condition $(\diamond)$ - or a necessary condition for condition $(\diamond)$ - using, instead of $P$, the cumulative distribution function $F$ associated to $P$?
- If yes, is there a way to approximate such a new condition as a linear constraint on $F$?